# tkinter validate multiple entry in for loop

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have created multiple entries with a `for` loop and I have to validate the entry values. If the values are good I want to update them in a class with the same function `ValidaFinanziatori` which is called on the press of a button.

I created the said button within the `for` loop:
it should pass to the function an index so that I can get the values from every entry widget which is organized in list within a dictionary.

But the button works only for the last entry. Can somebody help me please?

```py
class FinanziatoriSemplici(tk.Frame, FinanziatoreSemplice):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.numero_utenti=tk.IntVar()
        self.Finanziatori_Semplici = [] 

        self.labels_finanziatori = {
            'principale': [],
            'capitale_investito': [], 
            'tasso': [], 
            'tempo': []
            }

        self.entry_finanziatori = {
            'capitale_investito': [], 
            'tasso': [], 
            'tempo': []
            }
        tk.Label(self, text="Configurare I Finanziatori", font=controller.title_font).grid(row=0, column = 0)
        tk.Label(self, text="Inserire il numero di utenti da configurare").grid(row=1, column = 0)
        self.entry_utenti = tk.Entry(self, text="Inserire numero Utenti", textvariable = self.numero_utenti)
        self.entry_utenti.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.btn_utenti = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command= lambda: InizializzaUtenti(self.entry_utenti.get()))
        self.btn_utenti.grid(row=1, column=2)

        def ValidaFinanziatore(i):
                print(self.entry_finanziatori['capitale_investito'][i].get())
                #string_cap =self.entry_finanziatori['capitale_investito'][i].get()
                #int_cap = int(string_cap)
                #print(str(int_cap))

        def InizializzaUtenti(num):    
            self.numero_utenti = int(num)
            self.capitale = []
            self.cap = tk.IntVar()
        
            k=2
            print("k vale: "+str(k))
            for i in range(0, self.numero_utenti):
                print("inizio il ciclo numero: "+str(i))
                #MAIN label del finanziatore
                self.labels_finanziatori['principale'].append(tk.Label(self, text="Dati finanziatore numero "+str(i+1)))
                self.labels_finanziatori['principale'][i].grid(row=i*k+3, column = 0)
                k = k+1
                #Label capitale investito
                self.labels_finanziatori['capitale_investito'].append(tk.Label(self, text="Dati sul capitale investito del finanziatore "+str(i+1)))
                self.labels_finanziatori['capitale_investito'][i].grid(row=i*k+4, column = 0, sticky= "W")
                #Entry widget capitale investito
                self.entry_finanziatori['capitale_investito'].append(tk.Entry(self, text = "Inserire il Capitale investito dal finanziatore "+str(i+1), textvariable= tk.IntVar()))
                self.entry_finanziatori['capitale_investito'][i].insert(tk.END,0)
                self.entry_finanziatori['capitale_investito'][i].grid(row=i*k+4, column = 1)
                
                #capitale[i] = self.entry_finanziatori['capitale_investito'].get()
                k= k+1
                #Label Tasso di interesse############################
                self.labels_finanziatori['tasso'].append(tk.Label(self, text="Dati sul tasso di interesse del finanziatore "+str(i+1)))
                self.labels_finanziatori['tasso'][i].grid(row=i*k+5, column = 0,sticky= "W")
                
                print("prima del widget tasso i vale: "+str(i))
                #Entry widget tasso
                self.entry_finanziatori['tasso'].append(tk.Entry(self, text = "Inserire il tasso per il finanziatore "+str(i+1)))
                self.entry_finanziatori['tasso'][i].grid(row=i*k+5, column = 1)
                self.entry_finanziatori['tasso'][i].insert(tk.END, 0)
                
                print("dopo il widget i vale: "+str(i))
                k= k+1
                ############################## N.B. L'ultima label ha pady
                #Label Tempo di ritorno 
                self.labels_finanziatori['tempo'].append(tk.Label(self, text="Inserire il tempo di ritorno per l'investimento per il finanziatore "+str(i+1), anchor='w'))
                self.labels_finanziatori['tempo'][i].grid(row=i*k+6, column = 0, pady=(0, 10), sticky= "W")
                #Entry widget tempo
                self.entry_finanziatori['tempo'].append(tk.Entry(self, text = "Inserire il tempo di ritorno per l'investimento "+str(i+1)))
                self.entry_finanziatori['tempo'][i].grid(row=i*k+6, column = 1, pady=(0, 10))
                self.entry_finanziatori['tempo'][i].insert(tk.END, 0)

                validate = tk.Button(self, text="valida soggetto" +str(i), command = lambda:  ValidaFinanziatore(i))
                validate.grid(row=i*k+6, column = 2, pady=(0, 10))
                #Validate button                
                #validate = tk.Button(self, text="Valida soggetto" +str(i+1), command = lambda: ValidaFinanziatore(i))
                #validate.grid(row=i*k+6, column = 2, pady=(0, 10))
                k= k+1
```

Comment: You aren't using classes correctly. Please look at an object oriented programming tutorial.

Comment: In which why I'm mistaking? I'm using a backbone I found on stack overflow and I'm applying the concepts accordingly.

Comment: Well I can't really explain classes in a comment/answer but first of all you should unindent all of your functions (except `__init__`) once and add `self` as their first parameter. Then instead of calling `ValidaFinanziatore`, call `self.ValidaFinanziatore`. Instead of `InizializzaUtenti`, call `self.InizializzaUtenti`, ...

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks a lot for pointing out this huge mistake xD I checked back my entire code and adjusted it... It's the first time i oop with python... If I'm mistaking something else, please do point out, this has been a huge help

Answer (score 0):

use

```
validate = tk.Button(self, text="valida soggetto" +str(i), command = lambda i=i: ValidaFinanziatore(i)
validate.grid(row=i*k+6, column = 2, pady=(0, 10))
```

`lambda i=i: ValidaFinanziatore(i)` does the work you want..

but

`lambda:  ValidaFinanziatore(i))` will assign `i` to the Button every time a loop is made. so either every button will do the last assigned work or will not work

Comment: In the first line of code you posted, you are missing a `)`.